# Send full youtube video via Gmail (not link, the actual video)?

Tags: windows-7, video, gmail, youtube

My upload is horrible and when I have to send some video via Gmail to a friend whose office policy blocked youtube URL, I have to download it to my comp and then upload it to gmail message.

Is there a way to skip the comp step and to load youtube video directly into gmail message? For example, I attach a video to message, it gets attached by download speed and the guy on the other side can watch it without having to access youtube.

Comment: Does your friend not have a computer _that xe owns xyrself_ on which xe can watch YouTube videos at leisure?

Comment: Please write in English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a native feature available to do this, you can however do the following!!

When you have found the video you wish for your friend to watch, copy the URL

`www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4`

Use an online YouTube downloader like [Clip Converter](http://clipconverter.cc)

He can then download the suggested link in a format of his choice, if that site is also blocked, you can go through the process yourself and give him the final download link separately.

Disclaimer: I don't take responsibility for any trouble you might get into for doing this.

Comment: Disclaimer needed Dwayne! (similar to Moif's) :)

Comment: Thanks but my upload is horrible. That's the main reason. He will not get in trouble as the may access Gmail and the video will be inside as attachment.

Comment: You don't need to upload anything at all. This doesn't even require you to use GMail over and above letting him know what YouTube clip you want him to download.

Let me simplify it for you. You find YouTube clip. You email link to video. He goes to clipconverter.cc and pastes the link you gave him into the bar, he then chooses for example "MP4" and clicks download. Whalah, he has the YouTube clip downloaded without you having to upload it at all. IT Administrator's don't usually disable this site, or any of it's sister sites by default, so with careful usage you'll be able to use it repeatedly

Comment: I sure didn't understand you well as this may actually work. I'll try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

*dons Sysadmin hat*

There's probably a good reason why they've blocked Youtube and circumnavigating the policies could end up with your friend getting in trouble. If the Video is required as a legitimate business requirement then just get your friend to speak to his ICT department and allow either Youtube or the URL of the video.

Disclaimer: I've not had a coffee yet.

Comment: The reason is that people were using too much Internet in vain. We do not do that however. We're in the same project and I have to send him some youtube videos for this projects (mainly ideas, videos with cool grafics or video effects). It's not like he watches movies or something.

Comment: Well, as a Sysadmin, if it was put to me that there was a valid requirement to allow Youtube then I'd not have any problems with allowing it :)

You never know until you ask!

Comment: He knows. We asked them. It's governmental organisation and they have no understanding for our project. I wish admin is like you :).

Answer (score 0):

If your friends company has blocked Youtube, then embedding the video in the mail is not an option. Here are some alternatives:

a) Use a (web)proxy or a VPN tunnel

b) You download the youtube video with an addon for Firefox or Chrome. After that you upload it somewhere else on a file sharing site. 
EDIT: I only just saw that your upload is horrible. Forget the last option.

Comment: Good idea! Is there any online service to which I can submit a youtube or some other URL, and it will download the file and store it on its servers?